# Creates titles for layout on the fly

Tags: r, layout, plot

I am looking for a simple way of giving titles to each field in a layout, like this:

```
layout(matrix(1:8, nrow=2, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)) # Graph matrix

for (x in names(ftime.p)){
  plot(listz$x$data)
  title(x)
}
```

Notice that in my case, length(listz) = 8

I thought of using sapply instead, but the trouble is fitting the title() function in it:

```
sapply(listz, function(x) plot(x$data))
```

Comment: something along the lines of `sapply(listz, function(x) {plot(x$data); title(x)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example:

```
layout(matrix(1:8, nrow=2, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)) # Graph matrix
sapply(names(mtcars[1:8]), FUN=function(X) plot(mtcars[[X]], main=X))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `main` argument of plot, something like

```
sapply(listz, function(x)  plot(x$data, main=x))
```